# Delete named row in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, row

I have a named `textblock` row within a named data grid that I would like to delete.  Given that I know the name of the grid and the row, how do I delete the textblock?  I expected to find something like:

```
row_01.Delete();
```

But no such luck.  Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid Name="grid_01">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Name="row_01" Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Name="row_02" Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  Name="Tag_ContinueAs"  Text="Continue as Bejay" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 2):

IN order to delete a Row, use:

```
grid_01.RowDefinitions.Remove(row_01);
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use [RemoveAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.rowdefinitions(v=vs.100).aspx) of RowDefinitions by index in order to remove a row, example:

```
grid_01.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(INDEX);
```